# VBA Enter Value Based on Future Dates

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, nested

not sure if wording this correctly for the title, please edit as necessary.

I have code that currently works, does what I want.  However, it is not maintainable in perpetuity and I am looking to find a way to make a field or item update in a sheet based on future dates.  I have also tried nested functions but would prefer VBA.  I am thinking that I would need a 'For/Next' sort of scenario, but I am not certain.

Basically, I need to update fields based on if the current date of update is either past or between future dates based on half years.  So, if it is past Feb 1 2019, then the value is 'this'.  If the date is past July 1 2019, the value is 'this'.  This would go on for the next 10 years.

The sheet gets updated monthly and I want the code to know that as of this date, it is time to update these other fields or items.  Below is what I have for part of the code.  As you see, I just copied it down.  Seems messy and I am sure there is a cleaner way to do this.  My instinct says a for/next scenario but I do not have the skill to do this without assistance.

Thank you.

```
If Now() > #2/1/2019# Then
    Sheets("Mock up Content Page 1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 33")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = _
        "Semi1 2019 vs Last Year"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 54")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = _
        "Semi1 2019 vs Last Year" & Chr(13) & ""
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 77")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = _
        "Semi1 2019 vs Last Year" & Chr(13) & ""
    End If

    If Now() > #7/1/2019# Then
    Sheets("Mock up Content Page 1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 33")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = _
        "Semi2 2019 vs Last Year"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 54")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = _
        "Semi2 2019 vs Last Year" & Chr(13) & ""
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 77")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = _
        "Semi2 2019 vs Last Year" & Chr(13) & ""
    End If

    If Now() > #2/1/2020# Then
    Sheets("Analysis").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 33")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = _
        "Semi1 2020 vs Last Year"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 54")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = _
        "Semi1 2020 vs Last Year" & Chr(13) & ""
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 77")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = _
        "Semi1 2020 vs Last Year" & Chr(13) & ""
    End If
```

Comment: You think your current excel file will undergo no changes in the next 10 years? This seems unnecessary for a time frame this large.

Comment: Perhaps to you and I, but this is what I have been asked to deliver.  Something that can be handed off and will account for these changes.  They do not want it to have to be something they need to worry about updating.

Comment: You can convert your dates and use `Select Case`. You could create a loop using a dynamic year or something of the sorts. You can also create variables for your textboxes to shorten the code. Also, no need to `.Select` anything

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to do the trick:

```
Dim semiType as Integer
semiType = iif(Month(now())>6,2,1)

Dim msg as String
msg = "Semi" & semiType & " " Year(now()) &  " vs Last Year"

With Sheets("Mock up Content Page 1")
    .Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 33")).ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = msg    
    .Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 54")).ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = msg & Chr(13)
    .Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 77")).ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = msg & Chr(13)
End With
```

Comment: thanks Scott, I am going to give it a shot, let you know!